# How to verify that `sender` has only sent `two ints` in Mockito?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

Scala code:

```
class Sender {
  def send(objects: Any): Unit = ()
}

class User(sender: Sender) {
  def hello(): Unit = {
    sender.send("hello")
    sender.send(1)
    sender.send(2)
  }
}
```

I just want to test it sends correct ints, and not care about the strings:

```
"user" should {
  "send 3 objects, but two ints only" in {
    val sender = mock[Sender]
    val user = new User(sender)
    user.hello()
    there was two(sender).send(any[Int]) // !!! failed
    there was one(sender).send(1)
    there was one(sender).send(2)
  }
}
```

It failed with message:

```
The mock was not called as expected: 
sender.send(<any>);
Wanted 2 times:
-> at com.mytest.UserSpec$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(UserSpec.scala:50)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.mytest.UserSpec$User.hello(UserSpec.scala:63)
java.lang.Exception: The mock was not called as expected: 
sender.send(<any>);
Wanted 2 times:
-> at com.mytest.UserSpec$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(UserSpec.scala:50)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at com.mytest.UserSpec$User.hello(UserSpec.scala:63)
    at com.mytest.UserSpec$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(UserSpec.scala:50)
    at com.mytest.UserSpec$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(UserSpec.scala:46)
```

How to write it in correct way?

Comment: Can you please validate the answer if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `haveClass` to get a proper match

```
there was two(sender).send(haveClass[Integer])
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric, sorry for the late comment. I tested it, and found it's OK from SBT command line, but failed within IDEA. I also reported an issue to IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8668